# Flutter - How to prevent variables from being reinitialized when the state changes?

Tags: variables, dart, flutter

I have a **TabBarView** with stateful children and every time the tab changes, the child widget reinitializes and all of its variables are reset.

The child is basically a custom widget that uses the Future to load in data from an **HTTP** request. When it's done, I'd like to cache the response so when the user returns to the tab, it doesn't have to load the data via **HTTP** again. However, if I store the **HTTP** data in the stateful widget, it gets reinitialized to null (and so I have to load it again) when the tab changes.

How can I prevent flutter from reinitializing my tab content widget?

Comment: initialised variable in method void initState() {}

Comment: I wrote a post about that : https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc

Answer (score 0):

Can you create the `Future` which loads data from HTTP in the parent level(one level up to TabBarView) and send it to `TabBarView`. So, that it **will not load** on each tab change.

**Small code example:**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<int> data = dataFromNetwork();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              new Page(data), // I am sending the same data for example purpose
              new Page(data),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<int> dataFromNetwork() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {return 1;});
  }

}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<int> data;

  Page(this.data);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return PageState(data);
  }
}

class PageState extends State<Page> {
  Future<int> data;

  PageState(this.data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data.then((value) {
      print(value);
    });
    return Text("hi");
  }

}
```